# Perform iproute2 actions based on a match criteria

Tags: linux, centos, iproute2

Is there any way to use a wildcard or other matching criteria when using iproute2? I have multiple tunnel interfaces that follow a naming convention. Something like **ip tunnel del blah-*** (which gives the error: *ioctl: No such device*) would be great without having to resort to creating custom scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is pretty clear about that from what I can tell:

```
Usage: ip tunnel { add | change | del | show | prl } [ NAME ]
          [ mode { ipip | gre | sit | isatap } ] [ remote ADDR ] [ local ADDR ]
          [ [i|o]seq ] [ [i|o]key KEY ] [ [i|o]csum ]
          [ prl-default ADDR ] [ prl-nodefault ADDR ] [ prl-delete ADDR ]
          [ ttl TTL ] [ tos TOS ] [ [no]pmtudisc ] [ dev PHYS_DEV ]

Where: NAME := STRING
       ADDR := { IP_ADDRESS | any }
       TOS  := { NUMBER | inherit }
       TTL  := { 1..255 | inherit }
       KEY  := { DOTTED_QUAD | NUMBER }
```

NAME has to be a STRING, so it can't be a wildcard pattern. I know you hoped to avoid this, but your best bet would probably be to write a shell wrapper that does something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
PATTERN="$1"
for t in $(ip tunnel show | awk -F: '{print $1}' | grep -E "$PATTERN"); do
    ip tunnel del $t
done
```

Then just call your script like this: `deltunnels.sh "^blah-*"`

I think that should work.

Comment: Wasn't what I hoped for (not your fault!) but you gave me a definitive answer. Also, your script serves well for anyone else curious. Thank you!